# add and receive php parameter to javascript:GoTo('page')

Tags: javascript, php, goto

I have a page with two div. Let's say div B is hidden. There is a link to div B in div A. The link is like this :

```
<a  class='' href="javascript:goTo('page');" title="" >
```

I want to add a php id parameter in the link and I wanna know how it's received by other php script. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: could you explain this "There is a link to div B in div A" better?

Comment: @Tommy let's say I put a button that link to div B.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:

```
<a  class='' href="javascript:goTo('<?=$id?>');" title="" >
```

Comment: but you want to replace `page` with an id generated in php?